# contractions: "I have been" vs "I have a"

Tags: contractions

1. I have been waiting here
   a) I've been waiting here
2. I have a car
   a) I've a car

When it's comes to the first one the abbreviation is corrrect but what about the second one? It seems to be odd but what's your opinion is it okay to shorten the second example?

Comment: There are a lot of existing questions about I have/I've: [this covers the same topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75527/difference-between-ive-and-i-have)

Comment: It's not idiomatic to contract if you are using "have" in the sense of "to possess".  Usually in such sentences "have" will be stressed, and if you contract it then you lose the stress.

Comment: @BillyKerr The Brits use it but not the Americans.

Answer (score 0):

In sentence 1, **have** is functioning as an auxiliary verb, and as such it can always be abbreviated. In the second sentence, it's the main verb meaning possess. As a main verb meaning possess, it can't normally be abbreviated. If anybody can think of examples, please comment after reading the 'other meanings ' part of my answer.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have) claims that have meaning possess can be abbreviated, but in all of the examples that they quote, **have** is relegated to being an auxiliary verb, with **got** as the main verb.

> I've got two brothers

There are other meanings that definitely can be abbreviated as a main verb, for example suffer and experience, though these aren't marked as such in the Cambridge Dictionary.

> I've a headache
> I've a difficult situation on my hands at the moment

Comment: Yes, but it is only BrE to say: I've a headache. AmE does not use that. I just do not understand why people dv answers like this. They do not deserve it. I guess they just do not know.

Answer (score -2):

Both are valid. #2 is unlikely because it makes the sentence too "abrupt", too short.

I've heard people use a contraction, and then apparently conclude that the sentence is now too short and so they add unnecessary extra words. Like instead of saying, "Where is Alice?", they say, "Where's Alice at?" "Where's Alice" is grammatically correct, but it "feels" too short so they add the superfluous extra word "at".